# Marionette - modelEvents not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to use the `modelEvents` part of the `ItemView`, but for some reasons, it does not work.

I set up a simple test case, where I have a `CollectionView` with 4 `ItemView`s. When I click on one of the `ItemView`, then I change the first `ItemView`'s model within the `CollectionView` (`this.collection.models[0].attributes = {...}`). Even though the model's content changed, the change event does not fire.

Inside the `ItemView` I tried using the `modelEvents` with different options (`modelEvents: {"change": "functionToCall"}` ; `modelEvents: {"change:attributes": "functionToCall"}`), tried to use a simple `listenTo`, in the initialization function:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change", function(){
    this.functionToCall();
});
```

or

```
this.listenTo(this.model.attributes, "change", function(){
    this.functionToCall();
});
```

but none of them works.

It's not the first time that such hashes don't really want to work (such as the `ui: {}` and a few others) and I don't know what the problem is (I'm using Marionette 2.4.3 and jQuery 2.1.4 (just because Marionette needs it)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation found in Backbone (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes), I believe that the issue may be related to you updating the model via the attributes property directly. The documentation clearly states the models should be updated using `model.set(..)` - and not doing so will not fire the events associated with changing model data.